# Why does my Deep Convolution Neural Network architecture works better with small dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I developed a Deep convolution neural network for multiclass image classification with Keras and Tensorflow as the background. I discovered that my model works better when I used 1000 dataset compared to when I used 5000-25,000 dataset. I know deep learning works better with more dataset but reverse is the case for me. Any clue or assistance will be appreciated. Below is my code:

```
    from keras.utils import to_categorical
    from keras.preprocessing import image
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from tqdm import tqdm

    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    # Importing Keras packages
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Convolution2D, Conv2D
    from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
    from keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
    from keras.layers import Flatten
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    # demonstration of calculating metrics for a neural network model using sklearn
    from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef
    from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
    from sklearn.metrics import multilabel_confusion_matrix
    from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, average_precision_score,f1_score,recall_score
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, balanced_accuracy_score

    train_csv= pd.read_csv('dataset/ISIC_2019_Training_GroundTruth1k.csv')    # reading the csv file

    train_image = []
    for i in tqdm(range(train_csv.shape[0])):
        img = image.load_img('dataset/data/'+train_csv['Original'][i]+'.jpg',target_size=(32,32,3))
        img = image.img_to_array(img)
        img = img/255
        train_image.append(img)
    X = np.array(train_image)

    X.shape

    y = np.array(train_csv.drop(['Original', 'Filtered', 'Segmented'], axis=1))
    y.shape

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42, test_size=0.2)

    #initializing the CNN
    classifier = Sequential()

    #Adding the Convolution Layer
    classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (32, 32, 3), activation = "relu"))
    classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = "relu"))
    classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))
    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = "relu"))
    classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = "relu"))
    classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))
    classifier.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    #Flattening the layer
    classifier.add(Flatten())


    classifier.add(Dense(128, activation = "relu"))
    classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
    classifier.add(Dense(9, activation ="softmax"))

    classifier.summary()

    #Compiling the CNN
    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=60, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

    # evaluate the model
    _, train_acc = classifier.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=0)
    _, test_acc = classifier.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)

    print('Train Loss: %.3f, Test Loss: %.3f' % (np.amin(history.history['loss']), np.amin(history.history['val_loss'])))

    print('Train Accuracy: %.3f, Test Accuracy: %.3f' % (np.amax(history.history['acc']), np.amax(history.history['val_acc'])))

    # Convert to 1D
    yhat_probs = classifier.predict(X_test, verbose=0)
    yhat_probs[1]

    yhat_classes = classifier.predict_classes(X_test, verbose=0)
    yhat_classes[1]

    # Convert to 1D
    rounded_labels=np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
    rounded_labels[1]

    balanced_accuracy = balanced_accuracy_score(rounded_labels, yhat_classes)
    print('Balanced Accuracy: %f' % balanced_accuracy)

    matthews = matthews_corrcoef(rounded_labels, yhat_classes)
    print('Matthews: %f' % matthews)

    # confusion matrix
    matrix = confusion_matrix(rounded_labels, yhat_classes)
    print("Confusion Matrix: %s" % matrix)

    multilabel_matrix = multilabel_confusion_matrix(rounded_labels, yhat_classes)
    print("Multilabel Matrix: %s" % multilabel_matrix)

    precision = precision_score(rounded_labels, yhat_classes)
    print("Precision %f" % precision)

    f1 = f1_score(rounded_labels, yhat_classes)
    print("F1: %f" % f1)

    recall = recall_score(rounded_labels, yhat_classes)
    print("Recall: %f" % recall)

    average_precision= average_precision_score(rounded_labels, yhat_classes)
    print("Average Precision: %f" % average_precision)

    # ROC AUC
    roc_auc = roc_auc_score(rounded_labels, yhat_classes)
    print('ROC AUC: %f' % roc_auc)

    # plot loss during training
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.title('Loss')
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
    plt.legend()
    # plot accuracy during training
    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.title('Accuracy')
    plt.plot(history.history['acc'], label='train')
    plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'], label='test')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image: Result Screenshot with 1000 dataset]
[image: Result Screenshot with 5000 dataset]

Comment: you are overfitting to test data I suppose

Answer (score 0):

while using the large dataset you should try these techniques

- Try to use transfer learning on pretrained models https://keras.io/applications/
- Try to use data augmentation https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/
- You can also try K-fold cross validation for test train split https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html

Comment: Can I still augment when I have more than enough dataset? I have over 25,000 image dataset. Anyway, I will try the k-fold cross validation. Thank you.

Comment: you can try augment , but I think transfer learning will play the major role @God'sown

Answer (score 0):

It would be great printing out the evolution of training and validation loss during the 60 epochs. You can do it like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val_loss'], loc='upper right')
```

Maybe with samples, you should use more epochs, you could realize this looking at the evolution of the training loss.
You should also verify the distribution of the data you use. If the 5000 samples you use have a different distribution w.r.t the first 1000, that may be the cause of a different result. Try using more data, and including both the sets.

Comment: I reduced the Epoch to 60 because the evolution of test loss increases as the iteration increases but i notice the evolution of training loss was reducing as the iteration increases. I thought i was to be bothered by the test loss evolution and not training loss? Like you said, the distribution of data may also be the problem. I will check this out. Thanks for your insightful comment.

Comment: If in the first 1000 samples, all of them are similar, the comment you had by chris may be true. You could be overfitting the test set in the first case (by overtting the training set).